# will a nohup job adapt to the file change?

Tags: python, nohup

Say I am running a nohup job with a python file:

```
nohup python -u train_model.py 2>&1&
```

If I make a change to the python file and save it, will the nohup job be affected?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `nohup`; no, a running process won't be affected by changes in already imported files.

Comment: No, a running Python process will never be affected by changing the source code (unless you write code to explicitly do this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you run the python program, regardless of using nohup or not, it will be loaded into memory and will not be altered when you change the source code which resides in your disk.

Changes will apply only if you re-run it after the initial process complete, or if you run it in parallel.